# Only Static members can be initialised error in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to solve a code which was not written by me.I am new to flutter and having a hard time to understand it.

I have to call the MyHomePage widget and pass the page no. and an extension which will append the webUrl.But while appending the webUrl I am getting "Only Static members can be initialised error"

I tried using this.variable_name widget.variable_name ,this.widget.variable_name. I tried to many things and tried to understand about initialisers as well but everything seems to be going over my head. I will put the code below,please have a look

This is the code in the main file:

```
route = MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyHomePage(page: 0,extension: "name",));
```

These fields page: 0,extension: "name", I have implemented

The HomePage is like:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.page,this.extension}) : super(key: key);

  final int page;
   String extension;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<MyHomePage> {
  var bottomNavigationBarColor = Colors.white;
  PageController controller = PageController();
  var currentPageValue = 0.0;
  int bottomSelectedIndex = 0;
  bool loadFail = false;
  // InterstitialAd _exitInterstitialAd;
  var pages = {
    '0': DownloadRoute(),
    '1': HistoryRoute(),
    '2': WebviewRoute(
        title: 'Sample',
        link: 'https://www.sample.com'+widget.extension)//*****here is the error......I tried 
                                                           //this.extension and the variable name 
                                                           //extension itself,it didnt help,before on 
                                                         //www.sample.com was there***
  };

  void pageChanged(int index) {
    setState(() {
      bottomSelectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  void bottomTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      bottomSelectedIndex = index;
      controller.jumpToPage(index);
    });
  }


 
  Future<bool> _onBackPressed() {
    return showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            content: Text('Are you sure want to exit?'),
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                child: Text('No',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Color.fromRGBO(179, 80, 205, 1)),),
                onPressed: () {
                 
                  Navigator.of(context).pop(false);
                },
              ),
              FlatButton(
                child: Text('Yes',
          style: TextStyle(color: Color.fromRGBO(179, 80, 205, 1)),),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
                  SystemNavigator.pop();
                  },
              ),
            ],
          );
        });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    controller.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        currentPageValue = controller.page;
      });
    });
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
       
        if(isLoaded){
         
        }else{
          _onBackPressed();
        }
      },
      child: Scaffold(
          //primary: false,
          bottomNavigationBar: Theme(
            data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
                textTheme: Theme.of(context).textTheme.copyWith(
                      caption: TextStyle(color: Colors.white54),
                    )),
            child: BottomNavigationBar(
              type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
              backgroundColor: bottomNavigationBarColor,
              // selectedItemColor: Colors.white,
              // unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey,
              //fixedColor: backgroundColor,
              onTap: (index) {
                bottomTapped(index);
              },
              currentIndex:
                  bottomSelectedIndex, // this will be set when a new tab is tapped
              items: [
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: (currentPageValue == 0)
                      ? SizedBox(
                          child: Image.asset('assets/images/download.png'),
                          height: 30,
                          width: 30,
                        )
                      : SizedBox(
                          child:
                              Image.asset('assets/images/downloadunselected.png'),
                          height: 30,
                          width: 30,
                        ),
                  title: (currentPageValue == 0)
                      ? Text(
                          'DOWNLOAD',
                          style:
                              TextStyle(color: Color.fromRGBO(179, 80, 205, 1)),
                        )
                      : Text(
                          'DOWNLOAD',
                          style:
                              TextStyle(color: Color.fromRGBO(78, 78, 78, 0.6)),
                        ),
                ),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: (currentPageValue == 1)
                      ? SizedBox(
                          child: Image.asset('assets/images/history.png'),
                          height: 30,
                          width: 30,
                        )
                      : SizedBox(
                          child:
                              Image.asset('assets/images/historyunselected.png'),
                          height: 30,
                          width: 30,
                        ),
                  title: (currentPageValue == 1)
                      ? Text(
                          'HISTORY',
                          style:
                              TextStyle(color: Color.fromRGBO(179, 80, 205, 1)),
                        )
                      : Text(
                          'HISTORY',
                          style:
                              TextStyle(color: Color.fromRGBO(78, 78, 78, 0.6)),
                        ),
                ),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: (currentPageValue == 2)
                      ? SizedBox(
                          child: Image.asset('assets/images/tiktokselected.png'),
                          height: 30,
                          width: 30,
                        )
                      : SizedBox(
                          child:
                              Image.asset('assets/images/tiktokunselected.png'),
                          height: 30,
                          width: 30,
                        ),
                  title: (currentPageValue == 2)
                      ? Text(
                          'SAMPLE',
                          style:
                              TextStyle(color: Color.fromRGBO(179, 80, 205, 1)),
                        )
                      : Text(
                          'SAMPLE',
                          style:
                              TextStyle(color: Color.fromRGBO(78, 78, 78, 0.6)),
                        ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          body: PageView.builder(
            physics: new NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            onPageChanged: (index) {
              pageChanged(index);
            },
            controller: controller,
            itemBuilder: (context, position) {
              return Container(
                child: pages['$position'],
              );
            },
            itemCount: 3,
          ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
```

I tried many things like initialising constructor inside the state method and all but I cant understand what to do

**<<<<<<---EDIT-1----->>>>>>**>

[error after putting it in init state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQfF4.png)

**<<<<<<<<-----EDIT 2------------>**

```
    void main() {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      var appId ="";
      if (Platform.isIOS) {
        appId= '';
      } else if (Platform.isAndroid) {
        appId= '';
      }
      Admob.initialize(appId);
      runApp(MyApp());
    }
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        SystemChrome.restoreSystemUIOverlays();
        SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays(
            [SystemUiOverlay.top, SystemUiOverlay.bottom]);
        return GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);
            if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus) {
              currentFocus.unfocus();
            }
          },
**///////this is the line it is point to as line 42/////////////////**
          child: MaterialApp(
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            title: 'SampleApp',
            theme: ThemeData(
              primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
            ),
            home: MySplashPage(),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
    
    class MySplashPage extends StatefulWidget {
      MySplashPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      _MySplashPageState createState() => _MySplashPageState();
    }
    
    class _MySplashPageState extends State<MySplashPage> {
      bool internet = true;
      Route route;
      FirebaseMessaging firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();
    
    
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        // oneSignalInitialise();
        //FirebaseAdMob.instance.initialize(appId: FirebaseAdMob.testAppId);
        //Admob.initialize(getAppId());
        route = MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyHomePage(page: 0,extension: "",));
        super.initState();
    
        firebaseMessaging.configure(
          onMessage: (message) async{
            print('${message["notification"]["title"]}');
          },
          onResume: (message) async{
            print('${message["data"]["title"]}');
          }
        );
    
        myInterstitial = AdmobInterstitial(
          adUnitId: getInterstitialAdUnitId(),
          listener: (AdmobAdEvent event, Map<String, dynamic> args) {
            //if (event == AdmobAdEvent.closed) myInterstitial.load();
            handleEvent(event, args, 'Interstitial');
          },
        );
        showAd();
      }
    
      void handleEvent(
          AdmobAdEvent event, Map<String, dynamic> args, String adType) {
        switch (event) {
          case AdmobAdEvent.loaded:
            print('New Admob $adType Ad loaded!');
            break;
          case AdmobAdEvent.opened:
            print('New Admob $adType Ad opened!');
            break;
          case AdmobAdEvent.closed:
            print('New Admob $adType Ad closed!');
            break;
          case AdmobAdEvent.failedToLoad:
            print('New Admob $adType failed to load. :(');
            break;
          case AdmobAdEvent.rewarded:
            print('rewarded');
            break;
          default:
        }
      }
    
      void showSnackBar(String content) {
        scaffoldState.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
          content: Text(content),
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1500),
        ));
      }
    
    
      AdmobInterstitial myInterstitial;
    
      String getAppId() {
        if (Platform.isIOS) {
          return '';
        } else if (Platform.isAndroid) {
          return '';
        }
        return null;
      }
    
      String getBannerAdUnitId() {
        if (Platform.isIOS) {
          return '';
        } else if (Platform.isAndroid) {
          return '';
        }
        return null;
      }
    
      String getInterstitialAdUnitId() {
        if (Platform.isIOS) {
          return '';
        } else if (Platform.isAndroid) {
          return '';
        }
        return null;
      }
    
      String getRewardBasedVideoAdUnitId() {
        if (Platform.isIOS) {
          return '';
        } else if (Platform.isAndroid) {
          return '';
        }
        return null;
      }
    
    
      showAd() async {
        myInterstitial.load();
        int time;
        try {
          final RemoteConfig remoteConfig = await RemoteConfig.instance;
          final defaults = <String, dynamic>{'time': 1500};
          await remoteConfig.setDefaults(defaults);
    
          await remoteConfig.fetch(expiration: const Duration(hours: 1));
          await remoteConfig.activateFetched();
          time = remoteConfig.getInt('time');
          //print(time);
        } catch (e) {
          //print(e);
          time = 2000;
        }
        Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: time), () async {
          var isLoaded = await myInterstitial.isLoaded;
          if(isLoaded){
            print('loaded');
            myInterstitial.show();
            Navigator.pushReplacement(
                context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyHomePage()));
          }else{
            print('loaded not');
            Navigator.pushReplacement(
                context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyHomePage()));
          }
        });
      }
      GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldState = GlobalKey();
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          key: scaffoldState,
          body: Container(
            child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    gradient: LinearGradient(
                      colors: [
                        Color.fromRGBO(218, 84, 186, 1),
                        Color.fromRGBO(106, 72, 241, 1)
                      ],
                      begin: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                      end: Alignment.topRight,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Center(
                  child: Container(
                    child: Image.asset('assets/images/logo.png'),
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/4,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Is the error shown in the line of the main file which you have provided?
The error is related to where you initialize your route field I think. 
Can you provide more code of your main file?

Comment: No the error is when I hover over  link: 'https://www.sample.com'+widget.extension line..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you cannot access fields from the `widget` property when initializing a member property of your state.

A simple solution is: Move all your code for initialization of your state members to your `initState()` method.

This would look like:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.page,this.extension}) : super(key: key);

  final int page;
   String extension;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<MyHomePage> {
  var bottomNavigationBarColor = Colors.white;
  PageController controller = PageController();
  var currentPageValue = 0.0;
  int bottomSelectedIndex = 0;
  bool loadFail = false;
  // InterstitialAd _exitInterstitialAd;
  var pages;

  @override
  void initState() {
    pages = {
    '0': DownloadRoute(),
    '1': HistoryRoute(),
    '2': WebviewRoute(
        title: 'Sample',
        link: 'https://www.sample.com'+widget.extension)//*****here is the error......I tried 
                                                           //this.extension and the variable name 
                                                           //extension itself,it didnt help,before on 
                                                         //www.sample.com was there***
  };
    super.initState();
  }

  void pageChanged(int index) {
    setState(() {
      bottomSelectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  void bottomTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      bottomSelectedIndex = index;
      controller.jumpToPage(index);
    });
  }


 
  Future<bool> _onBackPressed() {
    return showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            content: Text('Are you sure want to exit?'),
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                child: Text('No',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Color.fromRGBO(179, 80, 205, 1)),),
                onPressed: () {
                 
                  Navigator.of(context).pop(false);
                },
              ),
              FlatButton(
                child: Text('Yes',
          style: TextStyle(color: Color.fromRGBO(179, 80, 205, 1)),),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
                  SystemNavigator.pop();
                  },
              ),
            ],
          );
        });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    controller.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        currentPageValue = controller.page;
      });
    });
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
       
        if(isLoaded){
         
        }else{
          _onBackPressed();
        }
      },
      child: Scaffold(
          //primary: false,
          bottomNavigationBar: Theme(
            data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
                textTheme: Theme.of(context).textTheme.copyWith(
                      caption: TextStyle(color: Colors.white54),
                    )),
            child: BottomNavigationBar(
              type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
              backgroundColor: bottomNavigationBarColor,
              // selectedItemColor: Colors.white,
              // unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey,
              //fixedColor: backgroundColor,
              onTap: (index) {
                bottomTapped(index);
              },
              currentIndex:
                  bottomSelectedIndex, // this will be set when a new tab is tapped
              items: [
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: (currentPageValue == 0)
                      ? SizedBox(
                          child: Image.asset('assets/images/download.png'),
                          height: 30,
                          width: 30,
                        )
                      : SizedBox(
                          child:
                              Image.asset('assets/images/downloadunselected.png'),
                          height: 30,
                          width: 30,
                        ),
                  title: (currentPageValue == 0)
                      ? Text(
                          'DOWNLOAD',
                          style:
                              TextStyle(color: Color.fromRGBO(179, 80, 205, 1)),
                        )
                      : Text(
                          'DOWNLOAD',
                          style:
                              TextStyle(color: Color.fromRGBO(78, 78, 78, 0.6)),
                        ),
                ),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: (currentPageValue == 1)
                      ? SizedBox(
                          child: Image.asset('assets/images/history.png'),
                          height: 30,
                          width: 30,
                        )
                      : SizedBox(
                          child:
                              Image.asset('assets/images/historyunselected.png'),
                          height: 30,
                          width: 30,
                        ),
                  title: (currentPageValue == 1)
                      ? Text(
                          'HISTORY',
                          style:
                              TextStyle(color: Color.fromRGBO(179, 80, 205, 1)),
                        )
                      : Text(
                          'HISTORY',
                          style:
                              TextStyle(color: Color.fromRGBO(78, 78, 78, 0.6)),
                        ),
                ),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: (currentPageValue == 2)
                      ? SizedBox(
                          child: Image.asset('assets/images/tiktokselected.png'),
                          height: 30,
                          width: 30,
                        )
                      : SizedBox(
                          child:
                              Image.asset('assets/images/tiktokunselected.png'),
                          height: 30,
                          width: 30,
                        ),
                  title: (currentPageValue == 2)
                      ? Text(
                          'SAMPLE',
                          style:
                              TextStyle(color: Color.fromRGBO(179, 80, 205, 1)),
                        )
                      : Text(
                          'SAMPLE',
                          style:
                              TextStyle(color: Color.fromRGBO(78, 78, 78, 0.6)),
                        ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          body: PageView.builder(
            physics: new NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            onPageChanged: (index) {
              pageChanged(index);
            },
            controller: controller,
            itemBuilder: (context, position) {
              return Container(
                child: pages['$position'],
              );
            },
            itemCount: 3,
          ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.It did help but when I ran the code,the app is throwing an Error saying invalid arguments

Comment: Where exactly is the invalid argument?

Comment: I have included the screenshot of the error in the edit of the question

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't help because I can't see what is in which line of your code.
You have to say me which line produces this error.

Comment: Thanks for sticking around so much.In the edit 2 of the question I have included the main file and even have inlcuded the line which is it pointing to.Thanks again

Comment: Great, but your error is not there where you marked. Your error is in Line 66 of your `_MyHomePageState` class. From the callstack I am assuming that this is the line where you concatenate your Strings. Please try out to replace 
`'https://www.sample.com'+widget.extension` with `'https://www.sample.com${widget.extension}'`

Comment: Because you never inject an extension into the constructor of `MyHomePage`. 
Instead of `MyHomePage()`. Call `MyHomePage( extension: '/url/extension/path' )` or whatever extension you want to have

Comment: Thanks for ur efforts ],whatever you said actually worked,but due I am not getting the required output I want,but still thats not ur fault.You have cleared that part which was needed for me.So therby I am marking this answer as correct

Comment: If the project is no secret, feel free to create a GitHub repository, give me permissions and create an issue there where you explain what you want and I will try to help you. My GitHub name is also NiklasLehnfeld

Comment: thanks for gratitude.I will see if I can actually do that after consulting my team mates

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize `pages` inside `initState()`.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<MyHomePage> {
  var bottomNavigationBarColor = Colors.white;
  PageController controller = PageController();
  var currentPageValue = 0.0;
  int bottomSelectedIndex = 0;
  bool loadFail = false;
  // InterstitialAd _exitInterstitialAd;
  var pages;

  @override
  void initState() {
    pages = {
    '0': DownloadRoute(),
    '1': HistoryRoute(),
    '2': WebviewRoute(
        title: 'Sample',
        link: 'https://www.sample.com'+widget.extension)
    };
    super.initState();
  }

  //rest of the existing code

}
```

Comment: Thanks.It did help but when I ran the code,the app is throwing an Error saying invalid arguments @Jigar Patel

Comment: @chethanv777333 It sounds like a completely different error than the error in the current question. You should post it as a separate question in itself.

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by the variable "String extension".
You cannot initialize a non final variable. You have to make the variable final . However, if the variable isn't final you could declare it in the state class.